# oom_kill counter in CentOS 7

Tags: ubuntu, centos, out-of-memory

In Ubuntu 20.04 I can find oom_kill counter at file `/proc/vmstat`. Where I can find this metric in CentOS 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not available in Linux 3.10 which comes with CentOS 7.0.

The change was commited two years later:

[*"mm/oom_kill: count global and memory cgroup oom kills"*](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/8e675f7af50747e1e9e96538e8706767e4f80e2c)